# When is mapping $g$ to $g^{-1}$ a group homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

When is mapping $g$ to $g^{-1}$ a group homomorphism? It just means that the map maps the identity to the identity and inverses to inverses. So does that mean it's only a homomorphism if the inverse is itself?

Comment: Do you find any of the answers below acceptable? If so, you should consider accepting one. If not, please indicate what it is you still find unclear.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well $\varphi(ab) = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and $\varphi(a)\varphi(b) = a^{-1}b^{-1}$. When are they equal for any $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I'm not sure... When they're commutative? When $a=b$? I read that it should map inverse to inverses, in which case a should be it's own inverse.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are two arbitrary elements of the group so you can't require them to be equal. The fact that we are dealing with $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ isn't relevant here. Let $c = a^{-1}$ and $d= b^{-1}$, then $cd = dc$, so the group is . . .? (You've already mentioned it in your comment).

Comment: So the group must be commutative then.  But I thought that homomorphisms mapped inverses to inverses. I guess that would just tell me a = a.

Comment: It does map inverses to inverses: $\varphi(a) = a^{-1}$ and $\varphi(a^{-1}) = (a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ which is the inverse of $\varphi(a)$.

Comment: Definition of group homomorphism: Mapping $\phi : G\to G$ is homomorphism, if $\phi(ab) = \phi (a)\phi(b)$ for all $a,b\in G$. Facts that homomorphisms map inverses to inverses and identity to identity are just a consequences of definition as Michael Albanese showed (for inverses).

Answer (score 2):

First observe that for any group $G$, the map $\phi$ defined by $\phi(g)  = g^{-1}$ is an injective surjection:  injective since $\phi(a) = \phi(b)$ implies $a^{-1} = b^{-1}$, hence $a = b$; a surjection since $\phi(a^{-1}) = (a^{-1})^{-1} = a$.  Furthermore $\phi(ab) = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} = \phi(b) \phi(a)$.

If $G$ is abelian, then $\phi(b) \phi(a) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ so that $\phi(ab) = \phi(b) \phi(a) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$, and $\phi$ is an isomorphism.  Similarly, if $\phi$ is an isomorphism, then $\phi(ab)  = \phi(b) \phi(a) = \phi(ba)$, whence the injectivity of $\phi$ forces $ab = ba$: $\phi$ is an isomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian.  QED.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: The term epimorphism would usually mean being a surjective homomorphism. But you are clearly using it differently here. Could you elaborate on what you mean by the term?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft:  Thanks; I edited the question to reflect your input.  When I wrote up this answer, it was late; I was tired, and the word *epimorphism* came to me as if in a dream! :)